# How do I dynamically update a TextView field from a ListView button?

Tags: android

On the same activity layout, I have a TextView field and a ListView with a button on each of its item. In my ListView array adapter, I have a button click listener inside getView() method where I am trying to "dynamically" update the value of my TextView field mentioned above.

So far, I have been able to update the TextView value with the help of an inflated instance but I can only see the updated TextView when I refresh the page by revisiting the activity page from the main menu.

As the last resolution, I have set it to restart the activity page within the buton listener inside the getView() method without having to do it manually. This isn't the best way as the user can see the page gets reloaded each time he clicks on the ListView item button.

Can you please let me know how I can update the value dynamically?

Following is my adapter class code:

```
public adapter( Context context, int resource, ArrayList<value> objects )
{
    super( context, resource, objects );
    layout = resource;
    array = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView( final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent )
{
    box = null;
    db = new database( getContext() );

    if ( convertView == null )
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( getContext() );
        convertView = inflater.inflate( layout, null );

        box = new holder();
        box.X = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.valueName );
        box.Y = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.valueNumber );
        box.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById( R.id.itemDeleteButton );
        box.button.setTag( position );
        convertView.setTag( box );
    }

    else
    {
        box = (holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    box.X.setText( getItem( position ).getX() );
    box.Y.setText( String.valueOf( getItem( position ).getY()) );

    box.button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            View view = View.inflate( getContext(), R.layout.activity_plan, null );

            list = (ListView) view.findViewById( R.id.listView );
            month = (Spinner) view.findViewById( R.id.inputSpinner );
            remainder = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.outputRemainder );

            adapt = new adapter( getContext(), R.layout.activity_item, array );
            array.remove( position );

            month_is = month.getSelectedItem().toString();
            db.removePlanData( month_is, position + 1 );
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            cursor = db.getHelpDataRows(month_is);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            val_is = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("value")));

            remainder_is = val_is - db.getCurrent(month_is);
            remainder.setText( String.valueOf(remainder_is) );

            // RESTARTING ACTIVITY TO SEE THE UPDATED TEXTVIEW VALUE OUTSIDE LISTVIEW.
            Intent intent= new Intent( getContext(), plan.class );
            getContext().startActivity( intent );
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}


public class holder
{
    TextView X;
    TextView Y;
    Button button;
}
```

Comment: It'd be useful if you could show your code

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have posted my code below. Sorry for the late reply. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it would be better if you write class names beginning with a capital letter. Next, as I understand your situation is : when you click a button on `listView`'s item, you should be able to change the textView's text outside of listView. It can be done by making the `textView` `public static` in your activity so that you will be able to access from other classes. For ex:

```
MainActivity.textView.setText("something");
```

In your main activity make the textView `public static`:

```
public static TextView textView;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.viloyatlat_frame); 

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

}
```

Comment: If it helped, please, accept my answer. Happy coding, Ras!